# Solving MDPs with polytope action spaces

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, optimization, markov-chains

A (finite) Markov Decision Process (MDP) consists of a finite set of states $S$, a finite set of actions $A_s$ which we will allow to depend on the state $s\in S$, an initial state $s_0\in S$ (the state on time step zero) a transition kernel which corresponds to every state $s\in S$ and action $a\in A_s$ a probability distribution $T(s,a)$ over $S$ (which represents the probability distribution of the state on the next step assuming the action $a$ was taken at state $s$ on the current timestep), a reward function $r: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a time discount constant $\gamma\in(0,1)$. We are interested in finding the optimal policy $\pi^\star$, i.e. an assignment of $\pi^\star(s)\in A_s$ to every $s\in S$ which maximizes the expectation of the total reward $\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t r(s_t)$. (It is also possible to consider policies which depend on past states and not just the current state, but one can prove there is always a stationary optimal policy.) As is well known, this problem can be solved efficiently by linear programming.

Instead of thinking about the set of actions as $A_s$, we can think about it as the simplex $P_s$ which is the convex hull of $T(s,a)$ for fixed $s$ and all possible $a$ (i.e. $P_s$ is a simplex inside the space $\Delta S$ of probability distributions over $S$). Since it's provable that randomizing the policy cannot improve the optimal expected reward, this substitution changes nothing important (even though now there's an infinite set of actions). Now, suppose that instead of simplices, we are given action spaces that are arbitrary polytopes $P_s$ inside $\Delta S$, represented by systems of linear inequalities. As before, the optimal policy can be assumed to take only actions which correspond to vertices of the polytope. However, now there can be exponentially many vertices (e.g. an $n$-dimensional hypercube is defined by $2n$ inequalities but has $2^n$ vertices).

**Question:** What is the computational complexity of finding an optimal policy for these "polytope MDPs"? Is it still polynomial time?